# Find the distributions of $\rho$ and $\theta$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ , $Y$ be independent random variables with distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Let $(\rho,\theta)$ be $(X,Y)$ in polar coordinates, $(X, Y ) = (\rho \cos (\theta), \rho\sin(\theta))$
Find the distributions of $\rho$ and $\theta$.

I have $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \theta=\arccos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$. The Jacobian matrix $J_g=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  \\
\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} & \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2} \end{pmatrix}$ with determinant $\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

$|J_g|^{-1}(\rho,\theta)=\frac{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y^2-x^2}\bigg|_{(\rho,\theta)}=\frac{(\rho^2)(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))\sqrt{\rho^2(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))}}{\rho^2(\sin^2(\theta)-\cos^2(\theta))}=\frac{-\rho}{\cos(2\theta)}$

then, using the change of variable theorem and the independence of $X,Y$ I get

$$f_{\rho\theta}(\rho,\theta)=f_{XY}(g^{-1}(\rho,\theta))|J_g|^{-1}(\rho,\theta)=f_{X}(g^{-1}(\rho,\theta))f_{Y}(g^{-1}(\rho,\theta))|J_g|^{-1}(\rho,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{\frac{-\rho^2}{\sigma^2}}\frac{-\rho}{\cos(2\theta)}{\Large{1}}_{[0,+\infty)}(\rho){\Large{1}}_{[0,2\pi)}(\theta)$$

I know that by integrating over one variable I get the density function of the other one but: Is this what I'm supposed to get up here? I'm thrown off by the $\frac{-\rho}{\cos(2\theta)}$ term that comes from the Jacobian. Is this alright?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You calculated the determinant of the Jacobian matrix wrong.

Comment: I missed a minus in the second row, thats what i got.

Comment: The Jacobian of the inverse map, $(r,t)\mapsto(r\cos t,r\sin t)$ is easier to calculate reliably; its inverse is what you should get.

Comment: Yes! but it shoud equal the inverse of this one right?

Comment: It should, but doesn't.  You made some mistake in your Jacobian.

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959094/321264.