# Independence of $X^2+Y^2$ and $\frac{X}{Y}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with standard normal distributions. It is known that $X^2+Y^2$ is a random variable with $\chi^2(2)$-distribution, while $\frac{X}{Y}$ is a random variable with $F(1,1)$-distribution. Is there any easy way to show that $X^2+Y^2$ and $\frac{X}{Y}$ are independent? I think that the brutal computation may work, but there ought to be an easy way.

Comment: I thought $\frac XY$ had a Cauchy distribution, while $\frac{X^2}{Y^2}$ had an $F(1,1)$ distribution

Comment: Thanks for correction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959094/321264

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically $X^2+Y^2$ is the radius of $(X,Y)$, and $X/Y$ depends on its argument, so they are independent.

To prove it formally, this idea of radius and argument is well summarised by the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform): there exist independent random variables $R$ and $\Theta$ such that $(X,Y)$ has the same joint distribution as $(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$. Then $(X^2+Y^2,X/Y)$ has the same distribution as $(R^2,1/\tan\Theta)$, hence we have independence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that $(X, Y)$ can be transformed to something like polar coordinate $(R, \theta)$. Then what is the distribution for $R$ and $\theta$? Sorry for that I have very little background of probability, but is independence of two random variables related to something like coordinate change? Or in other words, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and the Jacobi matrix $\frac{J(X, Y)}{J(R,\theta)}$ is invertible everywhere, can we conclude that $R$ and $\theta$ are independent?

Comment: For independence, the distributions of $R$ and $\theta$ do not matter, but it's respectively exponential distribution of parameter $1/2$ and uniform distribution on $(0,2\pi)$. I am not aware of such a connection between independence and coordinate change, apart that coordinate change can be a useful tool sometimes to prove independence. If you are new in probability theory then I understand my answer might appear a bit cryptic. I think it would be worth it, once you are more familiar with probability theory, to come back at it and try to understand why it is enough to say that.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that the pdf of the two-dimensional standard normal distribution $(X,Y)$ has the symmetries of a circle. This means that the pdf can be factored in polar coordinates as $f_R(r)f_\Theta(\theta)$ – with $f_\Theta(\theta)$ being uniform on the unit circle – so $R,\Theta$ are independent; since $R^2=X^2+Y^2$ and $\tan\Theta=\frac YX$, $X^2+Y^2$ and $\frac YX$ are also independent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for that I have very little background of probability. Suppose that $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are density functions for $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint density function for $(X, Y)$. Is it true that $f_{X,Y}(x, y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @Hebe Yes. See [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables).